# Can not make div truly 100% height

Tags: html, css

Here is a snippet:

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
html, body, #nav, #main {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    height: 100%;
}

#nav {
    background: #4D394B;
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}

#main {
    background: #FAFAFA;
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">Foo</div>
    <div id="main">Bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the #nav and #main divs are only 20px or so high per the text inside them.

Comment: So you want your `nav` and `div` to be `100%` in `height`?

Comment: both div takes 100% height. Check this link. http://jsfiddle.net/dnmzkq57/

Comment: What `doctype` are you using?

Comment: Both the divs are already 100% in height. I am not sure what is the problem here. http://jsfiddle.net/h9whnmxo/

Comment: By any chance are you using IE5?

Comment: I would recommend you to use `<nav>` and `<main>` these tags were maid to be used.

Comment: this is working great, share more information (browser, doctype)!

Comment: @Poteito main tag is not supported by IE

Comment: Doctype is html5 and using Chrome + Firefox.  The divs are only as tall as their content and not 100% height.  With the html, body and divs all set to 100% not sure what was causing it though the vh and absolute positioning answers worked below it seemed un-needed as above should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative with absolute positioning. Try this one:

```css
* {
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
}
#nav, #main {
    bottom:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
}
#nav {
    background:#4D394B;
    left:0;
    width:20%;
}
#main {
    background: #f00;
    left:20%;
    right:0;
    width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">Foo</div>
<div id="main">Bar</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution for you

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#nav {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ddd;
}

#main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="nav">Foo</div>
    <div id="main">Bar</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vh` unit, which is "viewport height", if it fits you need:

`html, body, #nav, #main { height: 100vh; }`

You do not have to set the height of `html` and `body` if you do not need.

`vh` unit is relative to the viewport height, so an element's height (set with `vh`) is not affected by the parent element's height.

`100vh` is equal to 100% of the viewport height.

Please check the [support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units) for browsers, before you use.